# AIC giving -infinity value

Tags: map-edit

I am new to data science.
While doing forecasting in ARIMA, the AIC of arima model is giving me infinity value.
because of that the oracle database is giving error while storing the aic into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arima model give you infinity value if your data is not successive equally spaced. 
ex. Jan, feb,march and june. (here june is not equally spaced.)
you can manually make aic to zero.

```
   fitscore<-fit$aic

  if ((fitscore=="-Inf")==TRUE||(fitscore=="Inf")==TRUE)
    {
      fitscore<-0
    }
```